# 'T' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T'

Tags: c++, class, templates

I've written a program to convert a sorted array to BST in C++ using classes. I'm getting the following errors:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'

error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

error C2065: 'T' : undeclared identifier

error C2923: 'Binary_Search_Tree' : 'T' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T'
```

The following is my program:

```
template <class T>
class Binary_Search_Tree {
public:
    struct Bst_Node {
        T value;
        Bst_Node* left;
        Bst_Node* right;
    };

    Bst_Node* root;

    Binary_Search_Tree();

    Bst_Node* sortedarraytobst(T* A, int start, int end);
};

template <class T> Binary_Search_Tree<T>::Binary_Search_Tree() {
    root = nullptr;
    std::cout << "Constructor called" << std::endl;
}

template <class T> Bst_Node* Binary_Search_Tree<T>::sortedarraytobst(T* A, int start, int end) {

    if(start > end)
        return NULL;

    int mid = start + (end - start)/2;
    Bst_Node* newnode = new Bst_Node();
    newnode->value = A[mid];
    newnode->left  = sortedarraytobst(A,start,mid-1);
    newnode->right = sortedarraytobst(A,mid+1,end);

    return newnode;
}

int main()
{
    Binary_Search_Tree<int> tree;
    int Array[10] = {1,2,5,6,8,9,12};
    int n = sizeof(Array)/sizeof(Array[0]);
    tree.root = tree.sortedarraytobst(Array,0,n-1);

    return 0;
}
```

Request help in this regard. I'm finding the usage of templates very confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the return value of the `sortedarraytobst` implementation, you should replace `Bst_Node*` with `typename Binary_Search_Tree<T>::Bst_Node*`. When put as a return type, it is seen as "outside the class", so it can't parse `Bst_Node*`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @VoidStar. That worked. But I have some questions: When do we need to use "typename" keyword? What do you mean by "seen as outside the class"? The struct is already defined inside the class right, so why cannot it be directly used as return type? Why is it required only for the return type and not the parameter(T* A) ?

Comment: If you try to build it, and you get an error like "dependent name is not a type" (differs by compiler), then you need to add `typename` there. After you do enough of this, its like a reflex... just add typename wherever the compiler wants you to :). But as to why, basically it's needed whenever you reference a type that depends on a `T` (any template argument) in order to access the contained type. This makes it a dependent name, requiring "typename" so that it knows it's a type. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name. But `T` isn't considered a dependent name on its own.

Answer (score 2):

As `Binary_Search_Tree<T>::Bst_Node` is a dependent name, the definition:

```
template <class T>
Bst_Node* Binary_Search_Tree<T>::sortedarraytobst(T* A, int start, int end)
{/**/}
```

should be replaced by

```
template <class T>
typename Binary_Search_Tree<T>::Bst_Node*
Binary_Search_Tree<T>::sortedarraytobst(T* A, int start, int end)
{/**/}
```

or (since C++11)

```
template <class T>
auto Binary_Search_Tree<T>::sortedarraytobst(T* A, int start, int end)
-> Bst_Node*
{/**/}
```

Comment: C++14 is required for a return type to be `auto`.

Comment: @VoidStar: Trailling return type was introduced in C++11, Return type deduction was since C++14.